# How to customize CMFCMenuBar in an MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, menubar, mfc-feature-pack

Is there a way to create dynamic menu items in the menu bar of an MFC applications created with visual studio 2008 style with menus not ribbon, I have plugins that add their menus dynamically how can I add them to that menu??? I see

```
//this is the menubar that i want to update
CMFCMenuBar       m_wndMenuBar;
```

Comment: I tried to update the CMenu* returned by GetMenu but no change reflected on the menubar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to create a new submenu. It can be filled by hand or loaded from resources. 
Then create a new menu button and attach submenu to it. After that update the menu bar. That's it.

```
CMenu menu;

if(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MY_MENU))
{
    m_wndMenuBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(0, menu, -1, _T("&MyMenu")), -1);

    m_wndMenuBar.AdjustLayout();
    m_wndMenuBar.AdjustSizeImmediate();
}
```

P.S. `menu` may be local because `CMFCToolBarMenuButton` constructor copy content from it.

Comment: InsertButton method is protected.

Comment: you are right, I was looking at the version of pointer InsertButton(CMFCToolBarMenuButton*.....) not the one of const ref InsertButton(const CMFCToolBarMenuButton&.....), yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to override:

```
CMDIFrameWndEx::OnShowPopupMenu(CMFCPopupMenu* pMenuPopup)
```

and put a placeholder menu item where you need a dynamic menu, then replace the placeholder menu item with your dynamic menu.

For an example look into the source code shipping with MFC:

afxframeimpl.cpp

```
BOOL CFrameImpl::OnShowPopupMenu(CMFCPopupMenu* pMenuPopup, CFrameWnd* /*pWndFrame*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way is probably to completely build a `CMenu` object, and then assign it to the menu bar: This makes the code almost compatible with the previous versions of VisualStudio.

1. Declare a pointer to an instance of `CMenu` in `CMainFrame` definition:

   ```
   CMenu *m_pMainMenu
   ```
2. Set it to `NULL` in `CMainFrame` constructor:

   ```
   m_pMainMenu = NULL;
   ```
3. In `CMainFrame::OnCreate()`, create an instance of `CMenu` assuming it was `NULL` before:

   ```
   SAFE_DELETE(m_pMainMenu);  
   m_pMainMenu = new CMenu;
   ```
4. [Modify it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k599xa5a(v=vs.90).aspx) at will with:

   ```
   pMainMenu->LoadMenu(),  
   pMainMenu->RemoveMenu(),  
   pMainMenu->AppendMenu(),  
   pMainMenu->InsertMenu(),  
   ...
   ```
5. Finally, associate the menu toolbar with this new menu by using [CreateFromMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984121.aspx):

   ```
   m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(m_pMainMenu->m_hMenu);
   ```
6. Don't forget to release `m_pMainMenu` in `CMainFrame` destructor to avoid leaks:

   ```
   SAFE_DELETE(m_pMainMenu)
   ```

Note: This is a very handy and safe macro:

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(a) { if (a) { delete(a); a=NULL; } }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` in property view window.
Let's say, you put a 'Text Capture' menu with 'ID_TEXTCAPTURE', and then you want to change the menu with 'Stop Capture'.

-in message map

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWndEx)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_TEXTCAPTURE, &CChildFrame::OnUpdateTextcapture)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

-event handler

```
void CChildFrame::OnUpdateTextcapture(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    if(pCmdUI->m_pMenu)
    {
        int pos;
        CMenu* mmenu = pCmdUI->m_pMenu;
        pos = FindMenuItem(mmenu, _T("Text Capture(&C)"));

        if (pos > -1 && IsCapture == TRUE)
        {
            UINT id = mmenu->GetMenuItemID(pos);

            //change menu text as 'Stop Capture'
            mmenu->ModifyMenu(id, MF_BYCOMMAND, id, _T("Stop Capture(&S)"));
            IsCapture = TRUE;
        }       
     }
 }


CChildFrame::FindMenuItem(CMenu* Menu, LPCTSTR MenuString)
{

    ASSERT(Menu);
    ASSERT(::IsMenu(Menu->GetSafeHmenu()));

    int count = Menu->GetMenuItemCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        CString str;
        if (Menu->GetMenuString(i, str, MF_BYPOSITION) && str.Compare(MenuString) == 0)
      return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I need full customization adding new items, deleting existing ones, not just text, I can change text, but not adding or removing.

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 I apologize about my careless. I do not have any method about that also. I hope you already solve this. Thanks.